# Connecting to MYSQL database when PHP file is in Virtual Machine

Tags: php, mysql, virtual-machine

I have my php files on Ubuntu 16.04 in my virtual machine, but I want MYSQL on my actual machine, which is my MacBook. How do I connect my database to those PHP files, so I can run the website? I want the content to be displayed on a database in a database on my Mac, though the code is written in my VM. Do I download MYSQL workbench on MAC or something? Mostly just having a problem with the database.

Comment: Have you tried using ports to access MySQL through?

Comment: Drop that all and open to yourself Docker universe! :-)

Comment: **_How do I connect my database to those PHP files, so I can run the website?_** question has zero sense. Usually we don't connect DB to PHP we do backward PHP to DB. To run a website you don't need PHP or DB you need a webserver (which could be Apache or Nginx for example).